# Java.Lang.Null.Pointer exception at onCreate for a FindViewById, What could cause this?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-xml, android-fragmentactivity

Previously I had an activity layout which I am now trying to replicate in a fragment as part of a viewPager.  I copied the old XML file and changed all the ID's in case of conflict.  I'm referencing the new XML layout for this fragment and the new ID's created.  But it gets this nullpointerexception when I run it.

Here is the logcat file
http://i48.tinypic.com/14ekq6s.png

Here is the part of the java file where there error occurs.

```
@Override
    public RelativeLayout onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        if (container == null) {
            // We have different layouts, and in one of them this
            // fragment's containing frame doesn't exist.  The fragment
            // may still be created from its saved state, but there is
            // no reason to try to create its view hierarchy because it
            // won't be displayed.  Note this is not needed -- we could
            // just run the code below, where we would create and return
            // the view hierarchy; it would just never be used.
            return null;
        }
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.one, null);
        ViewPager viewFinder = (ViewPager) getView();
//setContentView(R.layout.one);


        title = (TextView)     viewFinder.findViewById(R.id.frag_AA);  //ERROR xml id file probz
```

And here is the layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/frag_AA"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="I Am Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause is that the `viewFinder` is null.

I see you inflate the `R.layout.one`:

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.one, null);
```

but you don't use the returned view by inflater. 
`inflater.inflate()` returns a view, and this is where you should look for the `title` TextView.

Something like this:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.one, null);
title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.frag_AA);
```

(I never worked with ViewPagers, but taking a look [over this page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html), I have a feeling you are using it wrong, although I may not have right)

Comment: I can accept this answer if you first adjust the layout name to "one" now.  Sorry

Comment: When I answered your question it was `breed_frag1_layout`. But this does not matter too much, you got the idea what was causing the issue and how to solve it. Your condition is not fair, not fair buddy. :) If I will see a question from you in the future, I'll keep in mind this situation. ;)

Comment: I waited 2 days and just wanted to keep everything in the post the same.  Sorry.  can you swap it now?

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code..

```
View myview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.one, null);
title = (TextView)myview.findViewById(R.id.frag_AA);
```

because your inflater not inflate any layout it is `null` because if

`inflater.inflate(R.layout.one, null);` is return type.
It is return a view.
That's way this problem arise.